# Issues while trying to ssh instance over AWS:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

1. I had an instance which I could smoothly ssh. However, suddenly today I was not able to do it after starting. Since I had an EBS and had edited the /etc/fstab file, some of the answers at stackoverflow said it has some issues with ssh_config file. I detaches the existing EBS, mounted it to a micro instance so as to fix the broken volume. However, I was unable to ssh the new micro.
2. I terminated the instance in 1. Created a new one with similar config. Still cannot ssh.
3. Just for the sake of it, I created one without an EBS.
   I can ping both 2 and 3 but not ssh.
   The exact problem I am facing is this:

[aws ssh connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349641/aws-ssh-connection-refused)

Anyone, been there done that?

Comment: Try run ssh with `-vvvv` flag to get a sense what is going wrong

Comment: This is what it says:

http://pastebin.com/Le0Stjjs

Looks like proxy issue. However, I am able to access some other instances

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. It seems that AWS added a new set of IPs which was added to the necessary files since we access it behind a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the logs, there are chances that your SSH service went down for some reason. I've been there many times in the past few years, and restarting the instance through the EC2 Console did the trick for me sometimes.

My suggestion would be to restart the instance from the EC2 Console, and try SSH-ing into the server again.